# Synchronize local files with remote svn

Tags: svn

Svn on my local machine needed to be uninstalled, now i have local code which is not under version control and code under svn control on a remote machine, the code is exactly the same, but i dont know how to 'bind' my local code to svn again after reinstalling svn.
I thought of removing the whole local code and checkout again, but it sounds unsafe to me.
Is there any other way i can solve this situation without removing any code locally?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "bind" existing unversioned files with something in repository. You have to check out a working copy, but a safe way would be to checkout first, then compare the folder with the one you have, and only then delete the old folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the unversioned code on a safe location(backup or just a suitable place in your file system). It is good to remove the .svn folders. This can be done via

```
svn export
```

Afterwards, I would checkout again on a clear location, then paste the unversioned code over the checkout. The OS will first merge the files(if you previously had some unversioned files) and then SVN will denote if there are any differences.